# How to avoid the 404 not found error with PostGreSQL13 and PGADMIN4

Tags: apache2, pgadmin-4, postgresql-13

I'm trying to launch PGadmin4 with a PostgreSQL database but when I access `http://localhost/pgadmin4`, I keep landing on
`127.0.0.1 refused to connect`.

After Postgresql, I launched the databased and the server seems to work:

```
~ sudo systemctl status postgresql  
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-05-05 17:44:13 CEST; 11min ago
    Process: 8826 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8826 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

mai 05 17:44:13 hysterio-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU systemd[1]: Starting Postgr>
mai 05 17:44:13 hysterio-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU systemd[1]: Finished Postgr>
```

and the standard port 5432 is listening by the right process :

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:5432            
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 10886 postgres    5u  IPv4 134729      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 10886 postgres    6u  IPv6 134730      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

The installation of PGadmin4 required the installation of apache web server and it went correctly:

```
We can now configure the Apache Web server for you. This involves enabling the wsgi module and
configuring the pgAdmin 4 application to mount at /pgadmin4. Do you wish to continue (y/n)? y
The Apache web server is running and must be restarted for the pgAdmin 4 installation to complete. Continue (y/n)?
Apache successfully restarted. You can now start using pgAdmin 4 in web mode at http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4
```

I tried editing the pg_hba.conf files and postgresql.conf files to ensure the database is listening to 5432 on the localhost (127.0.0.1) but it hasn't done anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that Apache has been installed correctly? If you visit `http://localhost` do you see a generic landing page?

Comment: I get the `localhost refused to connect` error.

Comment: But I do get the generic Apache2 landing page on `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: There you go. Do you see anything at `http://localhost:8080/pgadmin4`?

Comment: There it is. I feel pretty dumb right now. thanks!